# printing an index from the linked list

Tags: c++

This part of the code is supposed to print the value of an index given by user!
I made it in very bad way like manually, any ideas about how can i turn this manuall code to an automatic one working with all indexes given by the user :)

```
    void Linkedlist::printNode(int nodeOffset)
{
    Node *temp1 = head, *temp2 = NULL;
    int ListLen = 0;

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List empty." << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Find length of the linked-list.
    while (temp1 != NULL) {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        ListLen++;
    }

    // Check if the position to be
    // printed is less than the length
    // of the linked list.
    if (ListLen < nodeOffset) {
        cout << "Index out of range"
             << endl;
        return;
    }


    
    if (nodeOffset ==1){
        cout << "Integer at index " << nodeOffset-1 << ": " << head->data;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(nodeOffset == 2){
        cout << "Integer at index " << nodeOffset-1 << ": " << head->next->data ;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (nodeOffset ==3){
        cout << "Integer at index " << nodeOffset-1 << ": " << head->next->next->data;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(nodeOffset == 4){
        cout << "Integer at index " << nodeOffset-1 << ": " << head->next->next->next->data ;
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Indices in C start from 0 not from 1.

Comment: `cout << "List empty." << endl;` <<-- the shift operator does not allow an operand of (char*) type.

Comment: @WKx The provided code is not a C code. I have changed the language tag from C to C++.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] which includes your function for outputting the entire list and demonstrates that and how you use your hardcoded version of outputting by index.

Answer (score 0):

I am  answering according to [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) because I feel it is appicable here.

Hint 1:
Did you not create the usual "output all of the list" function?
That is usually one of the very first steps, because it is such a useful debugging tool. Do that first.

If you have no idea of how to do that you will find many examples here on StackOverflow.
Then study how that function avoids to hard-code as you did.

Even in the shown code, there is similar code. Have a close look at the lines which determine the length of the list.

Try to output something near the `++` part. That gets you to the list output.

Hint 2:
Then try to only output when the count matches the index.

Comment: i made this one to print out the entire list but i dont know how this will help me with the other function  ``` void Linkedlist::printList()
{
    Node* temp = head;

    // Check for empty list.
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "List contains no integers" << endl;
        return;
    }

    // Traverse the list.
    cout << "List contains "  << len << " integers: ";
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
} ```

Comment: Please use the space and improved formatting options offered by editing the question, instead of squeezing code into comments.